# Как скачать вложение от пользователя? VK API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

При получении файла от пользователя получаю следующий словарь:
`{"attach1_type": "doc", "attach1": "742288495_658873163"}`

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='token')
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in VkLongPoll(vk_session).listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
        if event.attachments:
            if event.attachments["attach1_type"] == "doc":
                document = event.attachments["attach1"]
                response = vk.docs.getById(docs=document)
                print(response)
```

Когда пытаюсь получить больше информации о документе, используя docs.getById, то получаю пустой массив. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
from vk_api.exceptions import VkApiError

def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='token')
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    for event in VkLongPoll(vk_session).listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
            if event.attachments:
                if event.attachments["attach1_type"] == "doc":
                    document_id = int(event.attachments["attach1"])
                    try:
                        response = vk.docs.getById(docs=document_id)
                        print(response)
                    except VkApiError as e:
                        print("Ошибка VK API:", e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что файл был в закрытом доступе, а не в открытом